# Book class not numbering equations correctly and appendix reference does not work

Tags: table-of-contents, equations, indexing, appendix

I have a reference in my document to both the Appendix chapter and a reference to an equation in the Appendix.  The reference in the text does not produce a number and the equation in the appendix does not have an initial chapter number.

Also, the equation numbering in the main body is starting at zero.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{appendix} % for appendices
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\input{mwe1}
\appendix
\input{mwe2}
\end{document}
```

mwe1.tex

```
\chapter{One}

Equation~\ref{app:eq1} in Appendix~\ref{app:app1} shows that x = 1.

Here is another equation:

\begin{equation}\label{One:eq1}
  x + y = 3.
\end{equation}

Equation~\ref{One:eq1} shows that x = 2.
```

mwe2.tex

```
\chapter{Maths}\label{app:app1}

The equation is

\begin{equation}\label{app:eq1}
  x + y = 2
\end{equation}
```

The chapter numbers are not included in the Table of Contents.

The output of chapter One is:
[image: ChapterOneOutput]

Comment: You're missing `\mainmatter`. When `\frontmatter` is in force, chapters are not numbered.

Comment: egreg, can you please post your correct comment as an answer?